# Apply <style> rules to another element instead

Tags: html, css

I have a `<style>` element that applies some global styles, like `A { color: red }` as opposed to my stylesheet that styles `A { color: green }` (purely as an example).

How can I modify all of the styling in my `<style>` element so that are "contained" and only apply the styling to children of a parent element I specify.

`A { color: red }` becomes `#myelem A { color: red }`

`.myclass { display: none; }` becomes `#myelem .myclass { display: none }`

Would I have to find the `<style>` element, parse the contents, replace each selector then update the element contents with it fixed?

Is there an alternative to modifying the contents of my `<style>` element?

**Why am I doing this?** I have HTML that is stored in a database that I want to edit (this is a CMS). The HTML can contain `<style>` elements, and I cannot trust who writes the CSS to write it in scope. I could prevent users from using the `<style>` element, but I'd rather not. **I have no control over the original CSS**. Only what I get back in my server/clientside code.

If all else fails, I might have to load it into an iFrame... :(

---

Ooooooo Firefox supportes `<style scoped>` which only applies to the parent where the `<style>` element is located in the DOM. Too bad it's not supported in any other browser. :(

Comment: Doing this in Javascript doesn't make sense. Your CSS should be written for scoping anyway. I mean, how much CSS can there be that you can't do this manually?

Comment: Added explanation. The context shouldn't really matter.

Comment: An update on my situation: I've decided to drop a pure content editable solution for an iFrame. Sometimes you just need to admit defeat and go with what works best over what's more semantic.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you can use:

```
<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

Although it is only supported natively in Firefox, you can use this jQuery [polyfill](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) to get it to work in other browsers.

Comment: I was looking into a jQuery polyfill just before reading your suggestion. :) Thanks.

Comment: Despite my initial reservations, this is a very good question and something I never thought about during my CMS development which would have come in useful!

Answer (score -1):

Use the [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selector:

```
#yourElement > a { color: green; }
```

Comment: I have no control over the CSS unless I modify it after it's been given to me.

Answer (score -1):

JQuery:

```
$( "parent_type > children_type" ).css("param","value");
```

example

```
$( "#myid > div" ).css("display","none");
```

[here](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)'s a link

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xclme/mw3SM/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with what I'm asking.

Comment: On the contrary it does what it's supposed to do, so I don't know why you vote down.

Comment: In your example won't the original CSS still apply? Is your suggestion to manually change the CSS for every single line?